# How to use async/await using crypto.randomBytes in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

async function getKey(byteSize) {
    let key = await crypto.randomBytes(byteSize);
    return key;
}

async function g() {
    let key = await getKey(12);
    return key;
}

console.log(g());

console.log('hello - want this called after g() above');
```

I've been at this for an hour and I can't understand how to ensure that I get a key using async/await. I get a Promise-pending no matter what I do.

I've also tried this:

```
async function getKey(byteSize) {
    let key = await crypto.randomBytes(byteSize);
    return key;
}

getKey(12).then((result) => { console.log(result) })


console.log('hello');
```

... to no avail! Which was inspired by:
[How to use await with promisify for crypto.randomBytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61528374/how-to-use-await-with-promisify-for-crypto-randombytes)

Can anyone help me with this?

All I'm trying to do is to get randomBytes async. using the async./await block but ensure that it fulfills the promise before I carry on in the code.

Comment: Since you're not promisify'ing or passing a callback to `crypto.randomBytes()` it is synchronous so you can't await it. Additionally, you're not properly awaiting the promise returned by `g()` at the top level. That is why you always see the pending Promise in your `console.log()`

Comment: Is there a simple example available?

Comment: I've provided an answer that demonstrates my comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an extension of my comment on the question

> Since you're not promisify'ing or passing a callback to `crypto.randomBytes()` it is synchronous so you can't await it. Additionally, you're not properly awaiting the promise returned by `g()` at the top level. That is why you always see the pending Promise in your `console.log()`

You can use [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to convert [`crypto.randomBytes()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) into a promise returning function and await that. There is no need for the `async/await` in your example because all that is doing is wrapping a promise with a promise.

```
const { promisify } = require('util')
const randomBytesAsync = promisify(require('crypto').randomBytes)

function getKey (size) { 
  return randomBytesAsync(size)
}

// This will print the Buffer returned from crypto.randomBytes()
getKey(16)
  .then(key => console.log(key))
```

If you want to use `getKey()` within an `async/await` style function it would be used like so

```
async function doSomethingWithKey () {
  let result
  const key = await getKey(16)
   
  // do something with key

  return result
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  const crypto = require('crypto');
    
    async function getKey(byteSize) {
        const buffer = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    crypto.randomBytes(byteSize, function(ex, buffer) {
      if (ex) {
        reject("error generating token");
      }
      resolve(buffer);
    });
    }
    
    async function g() {
        let key = await getKey(12);
        return key;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

async function getRandomBytes(byteSize) {
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    crypto.randomBytes(byteSize, (err, buffer) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(-1);
      }
      resolve(buffer);
    });
  });
}

async function doSomethingWithRandomBytes(byteSize) {
  if (!byteSize) return -1;
  const key = await getRandomBytes(byteSize);
  //do something with key
}

doSomethingWithRandomBytes(16);
```

Answer (score -1):

If the callback function is not provided, the random bytes are generated synchronously and returned as a Buffer

```js
// Synchronous
const {
  randomBytes
} = await import('node:crypto');

const buf = randomBytes(256);
console.log(
  `${buf.length} bytes of random data: ${buf.toString('hex')}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function generateBuffer(){
  return new Promise((resolve)=> {
    crypto.randomBytes(32, (error, buffer)=>{
      if (error) {
        return reject(error)
      }
      resolve(buffer)
    });
  })
}
```

Then in an async function

```
const buffer = await generateBuffer()
```